# iOS - when a button is pressed, how do I get the system to make a remote call to my server?

Tags: ios, ios5, storyboard

I have been using a storyboard, and I have not gotten into the code much, and now it seems that it is time.

I have a form and when the submit button is pressed, do I need to put code to handle that into the .h or the .m file? Also, are there examples of handling a button and making a remote call that I can reference somewhere?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find Apple's [Your First iOS App](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007514-CH1-SW1) document helpful; it covers connecting buttons to actions in code.

As for making a remote call; there are many ways. I would suggest you look into NSURLConnection and friends as a stating place, but there are many, many libraries to help with this, such as RESTKit.

Comment: thank you very much - that is what I was looking for :) I saw their storyboard tutorials and they helped me a lot.

Comment: By the way, I know in Android there is something part of their library called AsynchTask which makes an asynchronous call to the server that can get a response and process it and display updates on the screen. What would be something like that in iOS?  Thank you again!!

Comment: An NSOperation is probably equivalent to that, though for a simple network operation, you might find a Grand-Central Dispatch block to be sufficient.